# Default UTF-8 encoder of StreamWriter doesn't return Preamble

Tags: c#, .net-core

I made a new `netcoreapp2.2` application and ran this code:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StreamWriter:");
        PrintEncodingConfiguration(writer.Encoding);
        Console.WriteLine("Encoding.UTF8:");
        PrintEncodingConfiguration(Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    return 0;
}

private static void PrintEncodingConfiguration(Encoding encoding)
{
    Console.WriteLine("   Encoding name: " + encoding.EncodingName);
    Console.WriteLine("   Web name:      " + encoding.WebName);
    Console.WriteLine("   Header name:   " + encoding.HeaderName);
    Console.WriteLine("   Body name:     " + encoding.BodyName);
    Console.WriteLine("   Preamble:      " + BitConverter.ToString(encoding.GetPreamble()));
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The constructor of `StreamWriter` contains this summary:

> Initializes a new instance of the System.IO.StreamWriter class for the specified stream by using UTF-8 encoding and the default buffer size.

So my guess would be that these two encodings above are the same. But here is the output of the program above:

```
StreamWriter:
   Encoding name: Unicode (UTF-8)
   Web name:      utf-8
   Header name:   utf-8
   Body name:     utf-8
   Preamble:

Encoding.UTF8:
   Encoding name: Unicode (UTF-8)
   Web name:      utf-8
   Header name:   utf-8
   Body name:     utf-8
   Preamble:      EF-BB-BF
```

As you can see, both encoders are providing the same name (and also encode/decode bytes and strings correctly AFAIK), but the stream writer doesn't provide the preamble, while the static encoder does so.

Any reasons for this odd behaviour?

Comment: preamble is an optional concept, and frankly I rarely see the UTF8 BOM in the wild, so which is "more correct" is questionable; if you *care* about whether or not you have a BOM: use the `new UTF8Encoding(bool)` constructor - then you can *tell it* whether to include it or not

Comment: While preamble is optional and rarely used I just wonder why *the same* encoding once returns the preamble and in the second case not. The question if and when to use the preamble is a different question.

Comment: define "same encoding" :) `new UTF8Encoding(false)` and `new UTF8Encoding(true)` are the "same encoding" in all respects except the preamble; that's the difference we're talking about here

Comment: Remember, you can [use the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs#L95)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Thanks. That what I liked to do, but couldn't find the right repo.

Comment: Not that it helps about this specific decision, I agree with Oliver that _default_ UTF8 encoding with preamble and default UTF8 encoding for `StreamWriter` without preamble is - at least - unexpected (and then a possible source of bugs). We may want `false` as default everywhere but that's another story

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preamble is optional *at the encoding level*; `new UTF8Encoding(true)` and `new UTF8Encoding(false)` provide UTF8 encodings with/without a BOM (preamble) as the only difference. `Encoding.UTF8` uses the "with" option, and clearly for some reason `StreamWriter` in this scenario is choosing "without", but both are valid - and neither is specifically "right" or "wrong".

If you care deeply about whether or not the BOM is present: supply the `Encoding` yourself explicitly, choosing the appropriate option.

Comment: I never said that one is "right" or "wrong". It is just odd that you won't get the preamble from the UTF-8 encoding if you ask for it. But you're right. If we need a specific behaviour we have to be explicit and instantiate the encoding with the correct value set.